# Caliburn.Micro.Telerik RadTab convention for IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, caliburn.micro, isenabled

I am using Caliburn.Micro.Telerik conventions [project](https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik).

I have view that dynamically loads telerik Tabs view models:

```
<telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="Items" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
```

I have set `IsEnabled` property onone of the Tabs view models to false, but that Tab is always enabled.

Is this supported? If not, how can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that CM doesn't allow more than a single property for element conventions and I'm not sure what the default property for `RadTabItem` is. You can always use an explicit binding using a style on the tab control

```
<telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="Items" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadTabItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

Or try using `ConventionManager` and setting the default convention for them (though this is probably already set to something in the Telerik CM framework)

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<RadTabItem>(RadTabItem.IsEnabledProperty, "IsEnabled", "?");
```

(You might have noticed the "?", I'm not sure what events `RadTabItem` has available and which should be the default event to trigger actions so you'd have to fill this one in yourself, see here for more info: [Caliburn element convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227966/caliburn-element-convention))

Edit:

Actually looking at the src, it seems no default convention is supplied for `RadTabItem`

https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/blob/master/WPF/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/TelerikConventions.cs

So it looks like you should go down the `ConventionManager` route

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using ConventionManager but was not successful.

I ended up using this XAML as suggested by Charleh and Valeriu at github Issue page (https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/issues/12#issuecomment-11840602):

```
<telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="Items">
    <telerik:RadTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadTabItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        </Style>
     </telerik:RadTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

Comment: No probs, would be interesting to step through the CM code and see why it's not binding this - probably something to do with the datacontext of the items being the list item and not the actual VM, you might be able to get round that by using `Bind.ModelWithoutContext` but you'd still have to add a style to tell the items what model they should be binding to!

Comment: Unless you have x:Name set in the xaml caliburn will not even visit that item in the binder. Caliburn's conventions are for binding named items in the view to named items in the viewmodel